# Intershop pipeline editor error "org/eclipse/xtend/typesystem/MetaModel"

Tags: macos, intershop

I cannot debug and handle Intershop pipelines on Mac OS X because the Intershop pipeline editor brings the following error "org/eclipse/xtend/typesystem/MetaModel"

[Intershop Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7t0ds.png)

Comment: Did you see the error log?

Comment: Can you provide the Studio version information?

Comment: I might have missed something, but intershop doesn't support max os. Did you find some document that says otherwise?

Comment: Eclipse IDE for Java Developers

Version: Oxygen.3a Release (4.7.3a)
Build id: 20180405-1200

by using Intershop Studio Update Site: http://support.intershop.com/estudio/

Comment: Mac OS X is not supported as production environment, but should work as development environment:
https://support.intershop.com/kb/index.php/Display/2D8656

Answer (score 0):

Installing the "Xtend IDE" should help. Just go to "Help --> Install new Software"

[image]